# Outlook blocking (freeze) when I create new email item with attachment?

Tags: c#, multithreading, plugins, outlook, block

I'm currently building a plugin for Outlook using C#, but when I create new email item in the thread, if I add attachments to email, my Outlook is blocking the user interface (freezing) until email created.

If I don't add attachments that not blocking the user interface Outlook.

So how can I fix that (not blocking the user interface outlook)?

This my code:

In Ribbon.cs, I have function button click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e){
    Globals.ThisAddIn.CheckProcessEmail();
}
```

and function CheckProcessEmail, I create new Thread:

```
public void CheckProcessEmail(){
    Thread threadCheckTest = new Thread(CheckTest);
    threadCheckTest.Start();
}

public static void CheckTest(){
    Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

    Outlook.MailItem item = application.CreateItem((Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));

    Outlook.MAPIFolder sentBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

    Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)sentBox.Items.Add();
    email.Subject = "Send Test";
    email.HTMLBody = "<div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>sad<o:p></o:p></p></div><b>Strong</b><h1>Hello</h1>";
    email.To = "a@test.com;b@test.com;c@test.com";
    email.BCC = "cc@test.com";
    email.Attachments.Add(@attachmentPath, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    email.Save();
}
```

Comment: you need to add some code!

Comment: I have just added code below :)

Comment: Please add it to the question :)